# Refactoring DAL using DI, being able to change the DAL later

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, dependency-injection, refactoring

What we currently have is an relatively old codebase, using EntitySpaces (doesn´t really matter, but it´s an ORM, which was nice to use back in the days, but with my recent EntityFramework experience it´s not so much anymore) as ORM for accessing a database directly. I´m now faced with the need to change many pieces of the application which currently rely directly on the EntitySpaces objects. This is not nice, but that´s the way it is right now. 
My general idea is to introduce a layer which introduces neutral, persistence-unaware objects, writing some sort of repository interface for getting, updating, etc. those objects and writing a (first) implementation that still uses EntitySpaces. Then i could refactor all those classes and components which currently use EntitySpaces directly. This would hopefully enable me to change the repository implementation later to use a webservice or EntityFramework.

Here are my questions / insecurities:

Generally, do i want to have one repository object sitting around somewhere or is it better to provide the components a factory which returns a (specific) repository? Maybe i could even split the repository in different interfaces for the different kinds of objects, which would result in some 20-ish interfaces i guess.

Lets say i have UI components which now perform a lot of operations on the database. If i rewrite them to work against a repository is it better to "give" those components an repository object or to rewrite this UI components in a way they don´t even have to know there is repository somewhere? Imagine there´s a dialog which lets you load a `Part` from the database, change it and send it back. This could be seen as some sort of `PartEditor` interface which could just be given callbacks to use when the user hits the *Update* or *Delete* button.

Would you even use a DI framework for this task? The application is relatively big, around 800k loc i think, without reused company-wide libraries. The alternative would be to just hide the concrete classes from all the components without using a DI framework, as to avoid introducing new problems. For the components using my new abstractions this shouldn´t make a difference, as those components should be written in a way that they don´t need to know the DI framework used, right?

I know this is quite abstract and maybe hard to answer, but i hope others have some experience with this sort of task. Im thankful for any pointers. As for question which DI framework to use, im completely open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Generally, do i want to have one repository object sitting around somewhere or is it better to provide the components a factory which returns a (specific) repository? Maybe i could even split the repository in different interfaces for the different kinds of objects, which would result in some 20-ish interfaces i guess.

I would create one repository per aggregate root. That makes it easier to maintain and test the code.

> Lets say i have UI components which now perform a lot of operations on the database. If i rewrite them to work against a repository is it better to "give" those components an repository object or to rewrite this UI components in a way they don´t even have to know there is repository somewhere? Imagine there´s a dialog which lets you load a Part from the database, change it and send it back. This could be seen as some sort of PartEditor interface which could just be given callbacks to use when the user hits the Update or Delete button.

You should use the repository pattern for that. You could switch to `DataAdapter` in the repositories for batch methods (if you have meassured that the EF performance is too poor for those scenarious). That's what so great with abstractions. You can fit the implementation after what you need without affecting the rest of the code.

> Would you even use a DI framework for this task? The application is relatively big, around 800k loc i think, without reused company-wide libraries. The alternative would be to just hide the concrete classes from all the components without using a DI framework, as to avoid introducing new problems. For the components using my new abstractions this shouldn´t make a difference, as those components should be written in a way that they don´t need to know the DI framework used, right?

I do use a DI framework when working with the database. It makes it a lot easier to let all repositories share the same connection and transaction (without escalating to distributed transactions).

You can read about an implementation that I've made for EF here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/

Answer (score 1):

> *Generally, do i want to have one repository object sitting around
>   somewhere or is it better to provide the components a factory which
>   returns a (specific) repository? Maybe i could even split the
>   repository in different interfaces for the different kinds of objects,
>   which would result in some 20-ish interfaces i guess.*

I would suggest you to create a generic repository that hides the domain-to-data translation (either using an OR/M or whatever) and later instantiate it using *inversion of control*:

```
// The factory hides who's the actual 
// repository implementation. In your case, it could be 
// EntityFrameworkRepository<T> or EFGenericRepository<T>
GenericRepository<Order> orderRepo = RepositoryFactory.Create<Order>();
```

The repository may have this methods:

- Add.
- GetById.
- Remove.
- GetByCriteria([expression tree]) (for example, `queryable => queryable.Where(...)`). This method may accept an input argument as `Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>>`. Entity Framework and NHibernate will let you implement it this way.

Using this approach - the generic repository - you avoid that 20, 30 repositories and, in addition, you've a base repository implementation implementing OR/M specific tasks in order to avoid spreading specific dependencies across your code base!

> *Lets say i have UI components which now perform a lot of operations on
>   the database. If i rewrite them to work against a repository is it
>   better to "give" those components an repository object or to rewrite
>   this UI components in a way they don´t even have to know there is
>   repository somewhere? Imagine there´s a dialog which lets you load a
>   Part from the database, change it and send it back. This could be seen
>   as some sort of PartEditor interface which could just be given
>   callbacks to use when the user hits the Update or Delete button.*

**The UI shouldn't know about the repositories. It should be the business domain the mediator of something like the UI and the repository.**

> *Would you even use a DI framework for this task? The application is
>   relatively big, around 800k loc i think, without reused company-wide
>   libraries. The alternative would be to just hide the concrete classes
>   from all the components without using a DI framework, as to avoid
>   introducing new problems. For the components using my new abstractions
>   this shouldn´t make a difference, as those components should be
>   written in a way that they don´t need to know the DI framework used,
>   right?*

Yes, use a DI/IoC framework. Don't avoid the unavoidable and don't reinvent wheels - which is a major problem than using third-party libraries -! I'd like to suggest you [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/) because its maturity, robustness and feature-rich framework.

Comment: ***1.*** What benefit would such repository give over using `IDbContext` or `ISession` directly? ***2.*** Why do you say `The UI mustn't know about the repositories. It should be the model.`. It doesn't make any sense unless you have anemic domain models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i don´t really get the part that jgauffin mentions, either. I guess i can´t avoid having specialized repositories for some classes. I will update my question a little after the next meeting which started right now...

Comment: @jgauffin 1) I don't want my business or UI to deal with infrastructure issues. 2) This is your point. You can still work with non-anemic domain models and don't delegate the UI or business the responsibility of instantiating the repository.

Comment: @Jobo the `GetByCriteria` gives you the power needed to avoid such specialized methods and the more specialized methods would be developed as _business_ rather than at the repository level. With the whole repository methods I've enough to do basically anything. Obviously, I gave you the hint, not the complete solution.

Comment: `I don't want my business or UI to deal with infrastructure issues`. Feel free to elaborate on that (update your answer). It's a vague explanation. Maybe with examples? 2) The repository is an abstraction used to load your business models so I don't see how that's infrastructure?. 3) What are you referring to when you say `model`. MVC? 4) (*i'm asking since I'm always interested in how others reason and solve issues, and not to be a pain in the ass*)

Comment: @jgauffin I'm @ work right now. It would be hard to extensively elaborate on this. 1) OR/M for me is infrastructure, I don't want to deal with DbContext or ISession or whatever. I just want to work with a domain context. 2) I'm not an MVC friend. Rather than a _model_ I call it _manager_. Either in an anemic or not anemic domain model, there're some operations that I wouldn't do in the domain object but in a _business manager_.